# How to deal with spammy links to an article I wrote in a different niche than the rest of my site?

Tags: links, negative-seo

I made the "mistake" of writing an article related to crypto (different from my main niche) and got tons of Blogspot backlinks from spammy blogs.

Is it going to help if I just delete the article and redirect to the homepage, or it's basically the same? Should I change the URL of the article? What is my best move?

Comment: Are those spammy links hurting your site?  Do you have a ranking drop that you can attribute to them or have you received a manual action from Google for link spam?

Comment: Google will probably just ignore the spammy links

Comment: I believe you can also disavow the links in your Google console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are sure that those spammy blog links are hurting your site in rankings, you should do nothing. Google works hard to make sure that rogue backlinks don't affect your site:

> In general we do automatically take these into account and we try to… ignore them automatically when we see them happening.
>
> For the most part, I suspect that works fairly well. I see very few people with actual issues around that. So I think that’s mostly working well.
>
> [Google’s John Mueller Answers Question About Negative SEO Attack - Search Engine Journal](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-john-mueller-negative-seo/310585/)

I also wouldn't consider changing the article's URL, I don't believe it will do anything except break your link. If you do end up deciding to delete the article, [do not use a home page redirect](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56440/is-it-ok-to-301-redirect-deleted-pages-to-the-homepage-in-order-to-preserve-link). Leave it as a 404 (or 410) page.

Comment: My organic traffic dropped by 50% and I was searching for the reason behind that. Also, I looked up at majestic and my scores were way worse than before. Citation flow has become high and trust flow has dropped drastically. Those Blogspot links are like 60% of my backlinks now.

Edit: I checked my analytics and saw that this article had only 4-5 page views in the last 3 months, so I'll delete it and leave it with 410 code.